# Changing datetypes of the datalabels

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying really hard to fix the datatype format of the datalabels. unfortunately, nothing is working out. I want the datalabels to have a fomat of 0.00%. How can I change it?

Here's a sample from the program.

```
Dim OAPList As Range
Dim SingleCell As Range
Dim Counter As Integer

Set OAPList = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E2:E" & lw)
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True

Counter = 1
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)

    For Each SingleCell In OAPList
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).DataLabel.Text = SingleCell.Value
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Next SingleCell
    .DataLabels.ShowValue = True
    .DataLabels.NumberFormat = "0%"
    '.DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionInsideEnd
    .DataLabels.Format.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangularCallout
    .DataLabels.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
End With

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Estimated Hours"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following line in For Each Loop:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).DataLabel.Text = Format(SingleCell.Value, "0%")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe change this line:

```
'With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed the code and ran the program. It shows the same result.